# My dependent variable is classified in categories ,which regression model to use

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, interval-censoring

My dependent variable is classified in categories as 5-10, 10-15 . Which is the best regression model for this kind of analysis.my dependent variable  asks the participant of the survey to mark the percentage of turnover due to innovations and the options are (1)less than 1% (2) 1%-5% (3)5%-15% (4) 15%-30% and(5) above 30% . Now please please help me to find the correct regression model, should I dummy code them and use them in linear regression or I should dummy code them and use for multinomial. my independent variables are all in likert scale. please help

Comment: The question is quite unclear to me. Try adding details regarding the following - - What are these dependent variables representing - are they just random names or is there some ordinality to them? - What is the range of this variable? - Is the dataset balanced if they are classes? - Any kind of special cases like large dataset, high cardinality of features etc? Depending on these questions the answers and best model will change.

Comment: If you have only two levels in the dependent variable then why should it follow multinomial instead of binomial?

Comment: My dependent variable is classified in categories as 5-10, 10-15 . Which is the best regression model for this kind of analysis.my dependent variable asks the participant of the survey to mark the percentage of turnover due to innovations and the options are (1)less than 1% (2) 1%-5% (3)5%-15% (4) 15%-30% and(5) above 30% . Now please please help me to find the correct regression model, should I dummy code them and use them in linear regression or I should dummy code them and use for multinomial. my independent variables are all in likert scale. please help

Comment: One option could be linear regression with maximum likelihood for an *interval censored response*

Answer (score 0):

For the dependent variable, I would start with ordinal logistic regression and see if the assumptions are met. There are various sorts of ordinal logistic, but the most common (and the place I'd start) is proportional odds logistic.

Likert scaled IVs are interesting. There's no common method, but I've sometimes used optimal scaling with some good results.

All then above is quite general - it may not be good with your particular data set. You might want to hire a consultant.